# optimizing CUDA 2d array access

Tags: c++, cuda, multidimensional-array

I am doing some very basic image processing on the gpu. I pass an array of filled with pixel RGB values stored one after each other.

I launch my kernel like

```
kernel<<<numBlocks,numThreadsPerBlock>>>(unsigned char * imageData, int val)
```

Grid size depends on how large my image is, but usually would be something like thousands of blocks of 512-1024 threads

In the kernel I do some basic computation and compare values straight from global memory.

```
int blueIdx = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x) * 3;
    int greenIdx = blueIdx + 1;
    int redIdx = greenIdx + 1;
float ypx = 0.299 * imageData[redIdx] + 0.587 * imageData[greenIdx] + 0.114 * imageData[blueIdx];

if( ypx > val) 
    imageData[blueIdx] = 255;
```

**Is there any way to optimize this type of access?** Essentially read value from 2d array, perform simple static multiplication, perform comparison, and then save new value back to global memory.

I have experimented with shared memory but my implementation it was slower. I am assuming that since threads are independent shared memory won't help.

Comment: For better answers, please state the kernel signature (types) and the size (width/height) of your problem. Also the full kernel launch parameters.

Comment: The principal optimization benefit I could imagine based on what little you've shown is to make sure your reads and writes are coalesced.  Based on what you've shown so far, I would not assume that "each block is loading the image data from global memory in a coalesced manner already".  Regardless of whether this is a byte array or some other size, handling the data via offsets is something that needs careful attention to achieve optimal coalescing.  And without data re-use (or inter-thread communication),  shared memory will not help.

Comment: 8- and 16-bit accesses never exhibit good performance, so you should consider using 32-bit ARGB pixels.  The benefits of coalescing will outweigh the 30% penalty in unused memory bandwidth.  Also, use cudaMallocPitch() and family to allocate the arra. The pitched memory allocations were added to CUDA specifically to enable global memory operations to be coalesced as you access adjacent rows.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it yet but depending on the cleverness (i.e. the lack of it) of the compiler using `uchar3` or even `uchar4` (for 32bit alignment) might be faster. I would have to look at the PTX code it generates for your kernel to make sure.

```
int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
uchar3 rgb = imageData[idx];
float ypx = 0.299 * rgb.x + 0.587 * rgb.y + 0.114 * rgb.z;

if( ypx > val) {
    rgb.z = 255;
    imageData[idx] = rgb;
}
```

Note that there is only a single read-operation. It just doesn't get any simpler than this. Well, moving the write-operation out of the conditionaly branch might be faster due to easier coalescence, but it also might be slower due to more write-operations. Experiment.

But really, things should be terribly fast already. I assume you could run this kernel on 1GB of data in about 5-10 milliseconds on a modern gaming GPU. Is that too slow for you? Are you sure it is the kernel that takes too long?

Comment: I get the following compiler error for uchar3 rgb = imageData[idx];

no suitable constructor exists to convert from "unsigned char" to "uchar3"

Comment: @smashbourne you need to change the type of imageData, its allocation, its initialization and getting the result back to uchar3 too.